# Assign value to relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Is there a way to assign a value to a relationship in Neo4j?

Say I have a couple of "people"-nodes with bidirectional relationship FRIENDS between people. What if I want to put a value on the quality of friendships, is that possible? 
E.g. Paul is 0.54 friends with Alice. Alice is 0.91 friends with Chestirecat.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @dmcgrandle Can't really see how this is necessary considering the nature of the question and the fact that it was answered one month ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Neo4j the generic name of a value assigned to a relationship is called [property](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-properties).

When [creating](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create/#create-create-a-relationship-and-set-properties) relationships you can add a property as such

```
CREATE (n:People)-[r:Friends { quality: 5 }]-(m:People)
```

You can also change the value of a property with [set](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/#set-set-a-property)

```
MATCH (m:People{ name: 'Mary' })-[r:Friends]-(m:People{ name: 'John' })
SET r.quality= 6
RETURN n;
```

To create a weighted friendship between Alice and Paul with a weight of 0.54 use the following CREATE:

```
CREATE (n:People { Name: 'Paul' } )-[r:Friends { quality: 0.54 }]->(m:People { Name: 'Alice' });
```

[image]

and to create a weighted friendship between Alice and Paul when the Alice node already exists with a weight of 0.91 use the following CREATE:

```
MATCH (n:People { Name: 'Alice' } )  
  CREATE (n)-[r:Friends { quality: 0.91 }]->(m:People { Name: 'Chestirecat' });
```

[image]

and to add a Friends relationship between Alice and Paul use the following CREATE:

```
MATCH (n:People { Name: 'Alice' } ), (m:People { Name: 'Paul' })  
  CREATE (n)-[r:Friends { quality: 0.62 }]->(m);
```

[image]

Comment: This will allow for unique friendship quality values between any pair of people?

Comment: No. To have them be unique for each relationship the CREATE needs to be like `()-[]->()` and `()<-[]-()`  Give me several minutes and I will update the answer.

Comment: @Dreuhn That should answer your two questions. The one in the posted question and the one in the comment. For any more questions please start a new question. StackOverflow is not a discussion board, it is for asking questions and getting answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have values also as an extra data on the relationship "FRIEND" then you can enter the values as an attribute of Relationship. When you click on the relationship you will see the values as well.